# BackBone collection fetch with parameter making duplicate call and not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, backbone.js

The Backbone model

```
define('PreferedDealerAddress.Model', function (){
'use strict';

return Backbone.Model.extend( {
    urlRoot: '/c.3927030/mazda-mstore-checkout-1-0/service/PreferedDealerAddress.ss'

  } );
});
```

The back bone collection

```
define('PreferedDealerAddress.Collection', ['PreferedDealerAddress.Model'], function (Model)
{
'use strict';

return Backbone.Collection.extend(
{
    model: Model
,   url: '../mazda-mstore-checkout-1-0/service/PreferedDealerAddress.ss'

, initialize: function(){
        this.fetch({
            success: this.fetchSuccess,
            error: this.fetchError
        });
    },

    fetchSuccess: function (collection, response) {
        console.log('Collection fetch success', response);
        console.log('Collection models: ', collection.models);
    },

    fetchError: function (collection, xhr, options) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        throw new Error("Books fetch error");

    }
  } );
});
```

Now In router I am creating the back bone collection and calling the fetch function by passing the parameter/query string like belwo

```
var search_params = {
                  'zip': zip
                };

 new PreferedDealerAddress.Collection().fetch({data: $.param(search_params)});
```

But it is making two AJAX call the first one is 
/mazda-mstore-checkout-1-0/service/PreferedDealerAddress.ss
/mazda-mstore-checkout-1-0/service/PreferedDealerAddress.ss?zip=92618

and the fetch method considering the first AJAX call which is returning a blank JSON array , due to missing query parameter.

The below  is screenshot from firebug.
[image]

Please help me, I can use $.getJson() and initialize the collection but that is not the proper way.

Comment: As a side note - I don't think you're instantiating what you think you are. The code `PreferedDealerAddress.Collection().fetch(...);` returns an XHR object (jQuery's by default), so using `new` won't create an instance of the PreferedDealerAddress collection. You should split the instantiation and fetching so you won't run into another problem in the future when you'll try tu use that "collection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually quite simple. Your first fetch is in the initialize method - the one without the data param:

```
, initialize: function(){
        this.fetch({
            success: this.fetchSuccess,
            error: this.fetchError
        });
    },
```

Then your second request is when you instantiate the Collection with the data param included.

So you just need to get rid of the fetch in the initialization.